# Keyboard Show Extra Space Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, keyboard, constraints

**Original Screen Shot:**

**1.**  When keyboard is not visible:

[image: screen Shot]

Which is fine.

**2.** Problem is when keyboard appears the above images goes to upper from original position from the textView and the keyboard as follows:

[image: Screen Shot]

Here is what I am trying to do:

[image: Screen Shot]

**Code:**

```
  func addKeyboardObservers() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

// MARK: - remove Keyboard Observers
func removeKeyboardObservers() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

// MARK: - keyboard show
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height - bottomLayoutGuide.length
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {() -> Void in
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: - keyboard hide
@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
 }
```

When i use this code then show me blank space screen shot given below:

[image: Screen Shot]

When i am comment these line screen shot below:

```
// MARK: - keyboard show

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
   // if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
    //    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
     //   let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height - bottomLayoutGuide.length
      //  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {() -> Void in
       //     self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight
       //     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      // }, completion: nil)
  //  }
}
```

[image: Screen Shot]

**This is my Main StoryBoard Screen Shot:**

[image: Screen Shot]

Can someone please explain to me how to solve this , i've tried to solve this issue but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you are trying to update view manually? use IQKeyboardManager for this

Comment: What is `self.bottomConstraint`?

Comment: @AtulParmar i  IQKeyboardManager used but same result

Comment: @mag_zbc its my mistake

Comment: you want to hide suggestion spelling view from keyboard?

Comment: Yes @AtulParmar

Comment: see my answer, I hope it helps to you

Comment: Thank you for you reply and time  i will check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following property to hide suggestion spelling view from a keyboard, I hope it helps you

```
textField.autocorrectionType = .no
```

[image]

Comment: If you have used IQKeyboardManager then disable for this view and go through normal keyboard

Answer (score 2):

You will see this "Gap" very often on new phones because they use 'safeAreaInsets' and to decrease the gap between your object and keyboard you need to do two things.

1. Get the Keyboard Height.
2. Get the safe area of your view, you can put it into a variable like this.

```
let safeArea = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom // This will result CGFloat
```

Not just decrease the two values and you will get the perfect output.

If you are using constraints then you can change the constant of your bottom anchor.

I will use TableView in this example, but you can apply this to any object.

```
var bottomAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint? // Creating variable for bottom constraint

// Setting Constraints
bottomAnchor = tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
bottomAnchor.isActive = true

// Modifying Constraint later (When Keyboard is Shown)
bottomAnchor.constant = keyboardFrame.height - safeArea
```

If you are modifying UIEdgeInsets then you can simply decrease the bottom value to safe area.

```
// When Keyboard is Shown
// E.g.
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardFrame.height - safeArea, right: 0)
```